# Javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure- Intermittent

Tags: java, ssl, https

I have a 2 java clients calling 2 different webservices in sequence. Below is the behavior I observed with issue.
Scenario 1: When I call 1st client and then 2nd client, everything works find w.r.t. https handshake

Scenario 2: When I call 2nd client and then 1st client, 1st client is giving handshake failure exception. 
For 2nd scenario I am unable to understand cause of handshake exception. I am giving below debug logs by providing  javax.net.debug as jvm argument. Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Java version used is 1.8, OS: Linux Ubuntu .Also we use custom truststore file of format .jks.

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1578906028 bytes = { 198, 139, 71, 122, 250, 174, 54, 216, 179, 134, 130, 78, 169, 242, 162, 218, 130, 56, 23, 126, 153, 63, 118, 240, 22, 110, 64, 41 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=api-uat.homesend.com]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 228
0000: 01 00 00 E0 03 03 5E 1C   32 AC C6 8B 47 7A FA AE  ......^.2...Gz..
0010: 36 D8 B3 86 82 4E A9 F2   A2 DA 82 38 17 7E 99 3F  6....N.....8...?
0020: 76 F0 16 6E 40 29 00 00   64 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  v..n@)..d.$.(.=.
0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
0060: 32 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 00   9D C0 2E C0 32 00 9F 00  2.,.+.0.....2...
0070: A3 C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  ../...-.1.......
0080: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00  ................
0090: 53 00 0A 00 08 00 06 00   17 00 18 00 19 00 0B 00  S...............
00A0: 02 01 00 00 0D 00 1C 00   1A 06 03 06 01 05 03 05  ................
00B0: 01 04 03 04 01 04 02 03   03 03 01 03 02 02 03 02  ................
00C0: 01 02 02 00 17 00 00 00   00 00 19 00 17 00 00 14  ................
00D0: 61 70 69 2D 75 61 74 2E   68 6F 6D 65 73 65 6E 64  api-uat.homesend
00E0: 2E 63 6F 6D                                        .com
http-nio-8095-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 228
[Raw write]: length = 233


]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 79 9F 1D 96 C6 B6 79 3F   22 8D 87 D3 87 03 04 60  y.....y?"......`
0010: 6A 6B 9A 2E 59 89 73 11   AC 43 D1 F5 13 FF 8D 39  jk..Y.s..C.....9
0020: 2B C0 F2 BD 4F 70 8C A9   2F EA 17 C4 0B 54 9E D4  +...Op../....T..
0030: 1B 96 98 33 3C A8 AD 62   A2 00 76 AB 59 69 6E 06  ...3<..b..v.Yin.
0040: 1D 7E C4 B9 44 8D 98 AF   12 D4 61 DB 0A 19 46 47  ....D.....a...FG
0050: F3 EB F7 63 C1 40 05 40   A5 D2 B7 F4 B5 9A 36 BF  ...c.@.@......6.
0060: A9 88 76 88 04 55 04 2B   9C 87 7F 1A 37 3C 7E 2D  ..v..U.+....7<.-
0070: A5 1A D8 D4 89 5E CA BD   AC 3D 6C D8 6D AF D5 F3  .....^...=l.m...
0080: 76 0F CD 3B 88 38 22 9D   6C 93 9A C4 3D BF 82 1B  v..;.8".l...=...
0090: 65 3F A6 0F 5D AA FC E5   B2 15 CA B5 AD C6 BC 3D  e?..]..........=
00A0: D0 84 E8 EA 06 72 B0 4D   39 32 78 BF 3E 11 9C 0B  .....r.M92x.>...
00B0: A4 9D 9A 21 F3 F0 9B 0B   30 78 DB C1 DC 87 43 FE  ...!....0x....C.
00C0: BC 63 9A CA C5 C2 1C C9   C7 8D FF 3B 12 58 08 E6  .c.........;.X..
00D0: B6 3D EC 7A 2C 4E FB 83   96 CE 0C 3C 69 87 54 73  .=.z,N.....<i.Ts
00E0: A4 73 C2 93 FF 51 10 AC   15 54 01 D8 FC 05 B1 89  .s...Q...T......
00F0: A1 7F 74 83 9A 49 D7 DC   4E 7B 8A 48 6F 8B 45 F6  ..t..I..N..Ho.E.

]
chain [2] = [
[

upcoming handshake states: client certificate[11](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
update handshake state: certificate[11]
upcoming handshake states: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 220, 209, 96, 98, 103, 88, 144, 4, 109, 90, 90, 136, 227, 139, 72, 89, 228, 46, 118, 178, 55, 187, 145, 208, 21, 176, 183, 107, 247, 58, 198, 174, 138, 164, 206, 14, 146, 82, 5, 181, 18, 179, 47, 197, 118, 69, 252, 221, 161, 126, 198, 168, 21, 234, 108, 187, 139, 115, 148, 125, 93, 34, 154, 57 }
update handshake state: client_key_exchange[16]
upcoming handshake states: certificate_verify[15](optional)
upcoming handshake states: client change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 77
0000: 0B 00 00 03 00 00 00 10   00 00 42 41 04 DC D1 60  ..........BA...`
0010: 62 67 58 90 04 6D 5A 5A   88 E3 8B 48 59 E4 2E 76  bgX..mZZ...HY..v
0020: B2 37 BB 91 D0 15 B0 B7   6B F7 3A C6 AE 8A A4 CE  .7......k.:.....
0030: 0E 92 52 05 B5 12 B3 2F   C5 76 45 FC DD A1 7E C6  ..R..../.vE.....
0040: A8 15 EA 6C BB 8B 73 94   7D 5D 22 9A 39           ...l..s..]".9
http-nio-8095-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 77
[Raw write]: length = 82
0000: 16 03 03 00 4D 0B 00 00   03 00 00 00 10 00 00 42  ....M..........B
0010: 41 04 DC D1 60 62 67 58   90 04 6D 5A 5A 88 E3 8B  A...`bgX..mZZ...
0020: 48 59 E4 2E 76 B2 37 BB   91 D0 15 B0 B7 6B F7 3A  HY..v.7......k.:
0030: C6 AE 8A A4 CE 0E 92 52   05 B5 12 B3 2F C5 76 45  .......R..../.vE
0040: FC DD A1 7E C6 A8 15 EA   6C BB 8B 73 94 7D 5D 22  ........l..s..]"
0050: 9A 39                                              .9
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 33 AB 7C 5F 3D 43 C2 13   A1 C8 CD 42 EE 30 77 0E  3.._=C.....B.0w.
0010: 24 E0 78 2E 09 40 2A 80   C1 81 3D 9D 8C 43 41 2C  $.x..@*...=..CA,
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 5E 1C 32 AC C6 8B 47 7A   FA AE 36 D8 B3 86 82 4E  ^.2...Gz..6....N
0010: A9 F2 A2 DA 82 38 17 7E   99 3F 76 F0 16 6E 40 29  .....8...?v..n@)
Server Nonce:
0000: BB 30 DB 15 15 B1 C9 E9   9F 5D D1 04 BF 7E 01 4A  .0.......].....J
0010: 67 55 2F FB 52 AE 6B 69   48 DB 0A 20 D4 83 77 5D  gU/.R.kiH.. ..w]
Master Secret:
0000: 82 EB E4 8B 06 FA 2D DD   C3 6A 4C A0 02 A4 19 95  ......-..jL.....
0010: 31 4B 94 14 AF BC 1D 37   3C 25 07 6A C9 88 64 41  1K.....7<%.j..dA
0020: 81 6F B2 D8 C2 0B E8 79   A5 E9 51 59 A7 3D 82 9D  .o.....y..QY.=..
... no MAC keys used for this cipher
Client write key:
0000: 11 BB BF 10 CF 88 23 0A   56 20 A7 CE EF D2 86 FC  ......#.V ......
0010: 69 C6 FE FD F0 2C 0F F0   4A F7 1B 2E D4 8E C3 D8  i....,..J.......
Server write key:
0000: A7 21 D1 BF F0 06 35 27   54 B1 C3 91 76 28 AF 43  .!....5'T...v(.C
0010: 51 EF 3C 8B 42 24 D8 FF   72 F8 AC 32 DB 5A 5E FC  Q.<.B$..r..2.Z^.
Client write IV:
0000: 56 74 40 AC                                        Vt@.
Server write IV:
0000: 41 33 77 8E                                        A3w.
update handshake state: change_cipher_spec
upcoming handshake states: client finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
http-nio-8095-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 03 00 01 01                                  ......
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 199, 30, 226, 215, 152, 74, 165, 126, 102, 248, 219, 89 }
***
update handshake state: finished[20]
upcoming handshake states: server change_cipher_spec[-1]
upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C C7 1E E2 D7   98 4A A5 7E 66 F8 DB 59  .........J..f..Y
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C C7 1E E2 D7   98 4A A5 7E 66 F8 DB 59  .........J..f..Y
http-nio-8095-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
[Raw write]: length = 45
0000: 16 03 03 00 28 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 7D 5C 49  ....(.........\I
0010: A5 98 02 36 CF 8A 04 B0   1E D4 D0 F4 25 65 D6 5B  ...6........%e.[
0020: 14 6D 18 91 EF 1F 08 A2   8B 67 36 59 63           .m.......g6Yc
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
http-nio-8095-exec-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8095-exec-2, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
http-nio-8095-exec-2, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8095-exec-2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
2020-01-13 14:34:45.884  INFO 23784 --- [-exec-2 : KWT2-TST-1d59nub55kbgg-1d59nub5827sx] HWSBinding_2_3Stub.class                 : Fee Inquiry Request XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><adviceOfChargeRequest xmlns="http://www.eservglobal.com/homesend/hws/2.0"><security><ns1:login xmlns:ns1="http://www.eservglobal.com/homesend/types/2.0">hws_almul_preprod</ns1:login><ns2:password xmlns:ns2="http://www.eservglobal.com/homesend/types/2.0">hws_almul_preprod</ns2:password></security><transactionId>4281624</transactionId><sourceUri>ewallet:327280</sourceUri><destinationUri>iban:FR021001100020100242012N37</destinationUri><amountInformation><ns3:currency xmlns:ns3="http://www.eservglobal.com/homesend/types/2.0">USD</ns3:currency><ns4:amount xmlns:ns4="http://www.eservglobal.com/homesend/types/2.0">393.09</ns4:amount></amountInformation><cbsType>P2P</cbsType><routingTag>FRA-BK</routingTag><ns5:vendorSpecificFields xmlns:ns5="http://www.eservglobal.com/homesend/hws/2.1"><ns6:vsf xmlns:ns6="http://www.eservglobal.com/homesend/types/2.1"><ns6:vendorId>2390</ns6:vendorId><ns6:fieldId>700</ns6:fieldId><ns6:value>KWT</ns6:value></ns6:vsf><ns7:vsf xmlns:ns7="http://www.eservglobal.com/homesend/types/2.1"><ns7:vendorId>2390</ns7:vendorId><ns7:fieldId>640</ns7:fieldId><ns7:value>P2P</ns7:value></ns7:vsf><ns8:vsf xmlns:ns8="http://www.eservglobal.com/homesend/types/2.1"><ns8:vendorId>2390</ns8:vendorId><ns8:fieldId>299</ns8:fieldId><ns8:value>EUR</ns8:value></ns8:vsf></ns5:vendorSpecificFields></adviceOfChargeRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
2020-01-13 14:34:45.884  INFO 23784 --- [-exec-2 : KWT2-TST-1d59nub55kbgg-1d59nub5827sx] HWSBinding_2_3Stub.class                 : Fee Inquiry  Response XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode><faultstring>javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure</faultstring><detail><ns1:stackTrace xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2020)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1127)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.amg.vcHomeSend.ows.HWSBinding_2_3Stub.adviceOfCharge(HWSBinding_2_3Stub.java:847)
    at com.amx.service_provider.api_gates.homesend.HomesendGate.getQuotation(HomesendGate.java:302)
```

Comment: You don't show any of your code or most of your debuglog, but the log suggests 'client1' needs to do client authentication and if you implement that by having or letting it use the default SSLContext and setting the sysprops `javax.net.ssl.keyStore*` in code at or near the call(s), and 'client2' also uses the default context (and was called previously), that won't work, because the `javax.net.ssl.*` sysprops are only read once per process, when the default context is first initialized, and any subsequent change is ignored, ineffective and useless.